# What is the best way to create new pandas dataframe consisting of specific rows of an existing dataframe that match criteria?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with 6 columns and several rows, each row being data from a specific participant in an experiment. Each column is a particular scale that the participant responded to and contains their scores. I want to create a new dataframe that has only data from those participants whose score for one particular measure matches a criteria.

The criteria is that it has to match one of the items from a list that I have generated separately.

To paraphrase, I have the data in a dataframe and I want to isolate participants who scored a certain score in one of the 6 measures that matches a list of scores that are of interest. I want to have all the 6 columns in the new dataframe with just the rows of participants of interest. Hope this is clear.

I tried using the groupby function but it doesn't offer enough specificity in specifying the criteria, or at least I don't know the syntax if such methods exist. I'm fairly new to pandas.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing

Comment: For future reference: please post code that demonstrates what you are trying to do.

Comment: Alex, I was weary of putting my code in here because a) I didn't think code would have been useful because I was just looking for a method that does a specific function and I thought a mention of the methods I've used would suffice; b) since my experiment is still under analysis I didn't want to show anything that might compromise the confidentiality of my data.

But I do understand that code does help get a context. So, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`isin()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and [`any()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) to isolate the participants getting a particular score in the tests.

Here's a small example DataFrame showing the scores of five participants in three tests:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,6,(5,3)), columns=['Test1','Test2','Test3'])
>>> df
   Test1  Test2  Test3
0      3      3      5
1      5      5      2
2      5      3      4
3      1      3      3
4      2      1      1
```

If you want a DataFrame with the participants scoring a `1` or `2` in any of the three tests, you could do the following:

```
>>> score = [1, 2]
>>> df[df.isin(score).any(axis=1)]
   Test1  Test2  Test3
1      5      5      2
3      1      3      3
4      2      1      1
```

Here `df.isin(score)` creates a boolean DataFrame showing whether each value of `df` was in the list `scores` or not. `any(axis=1)` checks each row for at least one `True` value, creating a boolean Series. This Series is then used to index the DataFrame `df`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly you want to query a dataframe for inclusion of the entries in a list.

Like, you have a "results" df like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'score1' : np.random.randint(0,10,5)
               , 'score2' : np.random.randint(0,10,5)})

   score1  score2
0       7       2
1       9       9
2       9       3
3       9       3
4       0       4
```

and a set of positive outcomes

```
 positive_outcomes = [1,5,7,3]
```

then you can query the df like

```
 df_final = df[df.score1.isin(positive_outcomes) | df.score2.isin(positive_outcomes)]
```

to get

```
   score1  score2
0       7       2
2       9       3
3       9       3
```